# Export a class after definition in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
// test.js
class Test

export Test
```

---

```
// index.js
import {Test} from './test'
```

This results in a syntax error with `Unexpected token`. What is the correct way to export a predefined class?

---

EDIT: It is required that the class definition is separate from the export.

Answer (score 11):

The correct way to do it is to use `export {Test}`.

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate

```
export {A, B};
```

Is the same as

```
// old style
exports.A = A;
exports.B = B;
```

Which require an `import` like

```
import {A,B} from "./somefile";
```

Which is the same as

```
// old style
var A = require("./somefile").A;
var B = require("./somefile").B;
```

---

However, you also could've also used `export default`

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    console.log("it's works");
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Which is the same as

```
// old style
exports["default"] = Test;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

Then import it like

```
import Test from "./test";
new Test();
// "it works!";
```

Which is the same as

```
// old style
var Test = require("./test");
new Test();
// "it works!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can both do

```
class MyClass { }

export { MyClass }
```

or

```
export default MyClass // no semicolon
```

And then

```
import { MyClass as Stuff } from './modulepath';
```

or (if you declare export default)

```
import { default as MyClass } from './modulepath';
```

or simply

```
import MyClass from './modulepath';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your test.js:

```
export class Test
```

Then

```
import {Test} from './test'
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to explicitly export it later because of some issues encountered with ES7 decorators.

Comment: then the answer from @vaughan is the way to go.